# ZKOSS Failed to process setAttr Cannot call method 'set' of null (TypeError)

Tags: javascript, zk

I am pulling my hairs.

I have ZK grid then within the grid there's another grid.
Both are bound to separate view models.

Think about it as a social network wall.

Outer Grid is a ViewModel that render posts.
Then for each post an inner grid is used which is bound to another ViewModel to render comments.

Okay, the issue is **"Failed to process setAttr Cannot call method 'set' of null (TypeError)"**

**HOW TO DEBUG THIS ERROR**. No server side error at all. By the way code works fine but every now and then I start get this error.

I am using **ZK 6.5.1.1** the latest version.

Note: I know without code it would harder to analyse the problem. But it's not too simple for me to post a portion of working or useful code snippet. So I would appreciate if someone knows how to debug this dreaded message. **Also I see other type of similar messages: Failed to mount: cannot call replaceWidget of null etc etc.**

Thanks

Comment: The way I debug this message is the way I debug any other error. I remove eliminate parts of code and see if error goes away. For eg. I will remove inner grid first and make sure the outer grid functions as expected. Then I will add a dummy grid (even a static one) and see if error occurs. Additionally I will also make sure my inner grid works independently and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to debug this kind of issue, you can try something like below:

.1. Open the debug mode (see ref)

**zk.xml**

```
<zk>
    <client-config>
        <debug-js>true</debug-js>
    </client-config>
    <library-property>
        <name>org.zkoss.web.classWebResource.cache</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </library-property>
</zk>
```

.2. Try reproduce this issue, here I create a sample to reproduce a similar issue by unbind a component manually as below (click 'test' button to see the similar error)

**test.zul**

```
<zk>
    <textbox id="tbx" />
    <button label="test">
        <attribute name="onClick"><![CDATA[
            String uuid = tbx.getUuid();
            Clients.evalJavaScript("zk.Widget.$('$tbx').unbind();");
            tbx.setValue("abc");
        ]]></attribute>
    </button>
</zk>
```

[image: test.zul loaded]

.3. See the error message in chrome's developer tooles then click the source link:

[image: error message in chrome console]

[image: after click the source link]

.4. Left click on the first line under setAttr to add a breakpoint.

[image: add breakpoint]

.5. Refersh page and click the 'test' button again, we can see the 'wgt' is null at right side, wgt usually denotes a widget (the Component at client side).

[image: retry with breakpoint]

.6. Now what we know is a widget becomes null and then ZK executing setAttr command of it, to debug this, we can simply log every uuid and className while bind_ is called (bind_ is a function of widget's life cycle, basically instanciate all dom elements of a widget) by Client Side Programming, and log all widget again while button clicked.

e.g.,

**test.zul (updated)**

```
<zk>
    <script><![CDATA[
        var allUuids = [];
        zk.afterLoad("zul", function () {
            var _wgt = {};
            // override zk.Widget,
            // basically zk.Widget is the
            // root of all widget classes
            zk.override(zk.Widget.prototype, _wgt, {
                bind_: function (a, b, c) {
                    // call original function
                    _wgt.bind_.apply(this, arguments);

                    // each widget has a uuid and className
                    allUuids.push({uuid: this.uuid, ele: this.className});
                }
            });
        });
        function showAllUuids () {
            var info,
                wgt;
            for (var i = 0; i < allUuids.length; i++) {
                info = allUuids[i];
                // get widget by uuid
                wgt = zk.Widget.$('#'+info.uuid);
                // show the old className and current status
                // you can also try record some more information as needed
                // e.g., parent, previousSibling, sclass, etc
                zk.log(info.uuid + ' was ' + info.ele + ' now ' + (wgt? wgt.className : wgt));
            }
        }
    ]]></script>
    <textbox id="tbx" />
    <button label="test">
        <attribute name="onClick"><![CDATA[
            String uuid = tbx.getUuid();
            Clients.evalJavaScript("zk.Widget.$('$tbx').unbind();");
            tbx.setValue("abc");
            Clients.evalJavaScript("showAllUuids();");
        ]]></attribute>
    </button>
</zk>
```

.7. Now we will get the log message below with the updated zul page after 'test' button clicked and let us know a textbox widget becoms null at client side, you can also check the response value in Network of chromes developer tooles.

[image: message with updated test.zul]

[image: response value]

Hope this helps

**References :**

[ZK Client Side Programming](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2010/April/Client_Side_Programming)

[Open the debug mode](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/Introduction/Debugging)

[bind_ in zk.Widget](https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/master/zk/src/archive/web/js/zk/widget.js#L2798)

Comment: Although I have not debugged the issue yet, instead I opted for an alternate route as time was of prime importance for me. Still I think what you have provided here gives a good answer to my original  question i.e. how to debug the ZK client side javascript errors. I am going to accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This particular error seems due to updating a component that is already detached/removed from ZK desktop. In other words, on server side you have a reference to a component that is cached but no longer attached to the component tree. When you try to update it ZK might try to sync its status with  its corresponding Widget on client side. However since it was detached, it no longer exists in client side so calling a setAttr on a null widget gives you this error.

Comment: Okay, what you say is logical. I am suspecting the same too but still it is hard to debug. I press a button 'Comments' to load comments i.e. update the Comments grid with the latest comments (commentsModel.addAll(commentsList)). Works fine. The Comments button can be toggled so clicking it again would remove all the comments from model (commentsModel.clear()). Still works. Now If I click once again (add comments back) I start getting this error. No error on server side, just client starts complaining about the detached object. I never detached the commentsModel or the comments grid. Any clues?

Comment: without a reproducing sample it is hard to suggest anything further. Please update the question with a simple sample.

Answer (score 0):

Although the best answer possible is already provided I wanted to add I was hitting this error and after debugging it turned out that there was a hflex="min" in a grid component.  I changed this to hflex="1" and the error went away.  This error started after updating zk version several versions at once so I'm not sure between which versions this change occurred but was a hard to identify. Hopefully simply searching your code base for hflex="min" might save someone some time... I would assume the same to be true for vertical flex.

Answer (score -1):

It come when we are setting something to a already element which is already set previously..

like

```
OFCchart chart = new OFCchart;
chart.setJSONScript("somedata");

//----- Some other place setting to the same---


chart.setJSONScript("somedata");
```